# How can I change the font of a web element everytime the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, responsive-design

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to figure out how to change the font everytime someone loads the page. The content of the text would be the same, but the font would be different everytime someone visits the website.

Is there a way to make a specific text element cycle randomly between 7-8 fonts on a webpage?

Comment: There's not enough information to give a detailed answer, you can take a look at [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to get started.

Comment: @Teemu - broken link

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Not for me? It navigates to MDN CSS variables page fluently.

Comment: how weird - now working ~ was giving 404

Comment: @Teemu What more information are you looking for? I'm looking for a way to have the font-family of a text element alternate randomly between 7-8 fonts whenever a webpage is loaded, so the font looks different to everyone who visits the website.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Does this link work for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--%2A

Comment: @Bearclaw We've no clue how you're currently styling the font on your page. Are you using some hardcoded CSS fonts or perhaps FontAwesome or perhaps some other font system? Which parts of the page should have that random font? Is it enough to add a font-family to `html, body`, and the rest of the page will then inherit the font, or do you need a different font for buttons and textinputs etc., are you using a normalizing stylesheet ..?

Comment: @Teemu I'm using a separate CSS stylesheet for the entire webpage. The font of one specific element in the body would be a different font everytime the page is loaded. Buttons and text input will have different fonts. Is there any other information you need?

Comment: Where have you stuck when trying?

Comment: Do you want the font to be chosen randomly or do you want the fonts to cycle? Can't have both!

Comment: @Teemu I know how to set a specific font for a web element, but I don't know how to have it change dynamically on page load. That was the question itself: I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: @AHaworth Chosen randomly between a set of 7-8 fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with three fonts, but you can use seven or eight with the same idea. First, define all fonts in the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: RandomFont1;
    src: url(./font1.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: RandomFont2;
    src: url(./font2.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: RandomFont3;
    src: url(./font3.woff);
}
```

Then make CSS variable that stores the (randomily) selected font. Make also a classname that uses the font.

```
/* this stores the selected font */
:root {
    --randomFont: RandomFont1;
}

/* all elements that have this class will use the selected font */
.random-font {
    font-family: var(--randomFont);
}
```

And lastly add some JavaScript to randomily pick one font to use.

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min);
}

// if you have seven fonts, replace 3 in the next line with 7
var fontIndex = randomInteger(1, 3);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--randomFont", "RandomFont"+fontIndex);
```

Here is the result when I'm refreshing the site:
[image: fonts changing randomily]

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a list of the font-family declarations you can choose from and then at load time invoke a bit of Javascript that gets a random number and selects one of them.

The JS can then set a CSS variable, say --font-family, which is what is used in your style sheet(s).

Here's a simple example:

```js
const fontFamilies = ["Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", "'Times New Roman', serif", "Courier, monospace" ];
const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * fontFamilies.length);
document.body.style.setProperty('--font-family', fontFamilies[i]);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
}
```

```html
 Some text to show change in font-family
```